# Google Chrome update service cannot start - happens again and again

Tags: google-chrome

I have experienced this problem multiple times on the same machine. When I try to update Chrome, I get an error ("Update check failed to start - error code 3: 0x80080005"):

[image]

I notice that the Google Update service cannot start ("The system cannot find the file specified"):

[image]

**The fix is very simple:** Run the Chrome installer again. It will leave your data intact and fix the service.

But why does this problem keep occurring every few months on my machine? It's a Windows 10 installation.

Comment: Have you checked your disk for any corruption?  When you get that error, what file is the gupdate service pointing to?  Do you have any strict digital signature code-signing policies enforced on your system?  Did you recently uninstall another Google application (eg, Google Earth)?  Have you checked your anti-virus Quarantine?

Comment: I need to check where that service definition points to, that's a good idea. No corruption, I recently checked and I check quite frequently. The other ones are also a no.